# FileWriter writing into file

Tags: java, java-io, filewriter

How do I use `FileWriter` to actually write into a file and then open it on notepad and see what I wrote? This is what I tried so far:

```
package Experimental;

import java.io.*;

public class IO {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

       File f = new File("testFile.txt");

       //Outputting into a file
       try {

          PrintWriter filePrint = new PrintWriter(
             new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f,true))
          );
          filePrint.println("testing, testing, printing into a file (apparently)");
       } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Improve your formatting please

Comment: What happens if you open the file in notepad? Does it open it?

Comment: What is wrong with the code? Did you get any exception?

Comment: Thanks for editing the code @Aurélien Thieriot, the opening braces on a different line were really bugging me!

Comment: have you tried to google it?

Comment: solve it, thank you anyway, and about the formatting, it's just a bad habit, working on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget to [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close()) your `FileWriter` once you are done writing to it.

Comment: I think it's important to `flush` too.

Comment: A call to `close` automatically flushes a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You should *flush* and *close* the `PrintWriter` like this:

```
File file = new File("testFile.txt");
PrintWriter filePrint = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));

try 
{
  try 
  {
    filePrint.println("testing, testing, printing into a file (apparently)");
    filePrint.flush();
  } 
  finally
  {
    filePrint.close();
  }
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: some special reason why to have inner try there ?

Comment: @Betlista the `close` method can throw an `IOException`